# Change the image dimension on the woocommerce product page

Tags: woocommerce

I took inspiration from this thread [Woocommerce: Featured image different than product image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636593/woocommerce-featured-image-different-than-product-image) and made one of the gallery page as the featured image/ big image on the product page on a Woocommerce theme website.

However, since it's picking on the small images from the thumbnails gallery, the dimension is not being changed and the image thus goes blurry. The HTML in it is restricting it. How can I increase width and height the primary image/big image on the product single page.

For reference you can visit this link http://fliptales2.davcommdev.com/product/aaron-camel/ . You can find the image is blurry and the HTML of this big image is 200x159.

Answer (score 0):

I got it done anyway. Here are the codes.. (with ref: to [Woocommerce: Featured image different than product image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636593/woocommerce-featured-image-different-than-product-image))

```
<div class="images">

<?php

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    isset ($placeholder_width)? : $placeholder_width=0;
    isset ($placeholder_height)? : $placeholder_height=0;

    if ( $attachment_ids ) {
        $attachment_id = $attachment_ids[0];

    if ( ! $placeholder_width )
        $placeholder_width = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_width' );
    if ( ! $placeholder_height )
        $placeholder_height = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_height' );

        $output = '<div class="imagewrapper">';

        //$classes = array( 'imagewrapper' );
        $classes = array();
        $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

        if ( $image_link ) {

        $image       = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) );
        $image_class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $classes ) );
        $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s"  rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

        } else {

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="Placeholder" />', woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() ), $post->ID );

        }

    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>
```