# Woocommerce: Featured image different than product image revision needed

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, image-gallery, wordpress-featured-image

i've been trying to implement the modification discussed on the page: [Woocommerce: Featured image different than product image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636593/woocommerce-featured-image-different-than-product-image/24684263#24684263)

But it doesn't seem to work with the latest release of woocommerce v2.4.7
does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Here is the current code from v2.4.7 i'm trying to replace. when the fix is applied it breaks the page.

```
<div class="images">

    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

            $image_title    = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
            $image_caption  = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt;
            $image_link     = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
            $image          = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ), array(
                'title' => $image_title,
                'alt'   => $image_title
                ) );

            $attachment_count = count( $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids() );

            if ( $attachment_count > 0 ) {
                $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
            } else {
                $gallery = '';
            }

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_caption, $image ), $post->ID );

        } else {

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" />', wc_placeholder_img_src(), __( 'Placeholder', 'woocommerce' ) ), $post->ID );

        }
    ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>

</div>
```

And here the original modified code from the page mentioned above:

```
<div class="images">

<?php

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    isset ($placeholder_width)? : $placeholder_width=0;
    isset ($placeholder_height)? : $placeholder_height=0;

    if ( $attachment_ids ) {
        $attachment_id = $attachment_ids[0];

    if ( ! $placeholder_width )
        $placeholder_width = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_width' );
    if ( ! $placeholder_height )
        $placeholder_height = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_height' );

        $output = '<div class="imagewrapper">';

        //$classes = array( 'imagewrapper' );
        $classes = array();
        $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

        if ( $image_link ) {

        $image       = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ) );
        $image_class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $classes ) );
        $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s"  rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

        } else {

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="Placeholder" />', woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() ), $post->ID );

        }

    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>

</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Darrell

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same here, but this seems to have done the trick for me:

```
<div class="images">

<?php

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    isset ($placeholder_width)? : $placeholder_width=0;
    isset ($placeholder_height)? : $placeholder_height=0;

    if ( $attachment_ids ) {
        $attachment_id = $attachment_ids[0];

    if ( ! $placeholder_width )
        $size = wc_get_image_size( 'shop_catalog' );
        $placeholder_width = $size['width'];
    if ( ! $placeholder_height )
        $size = wc_get_image_size( 'shop_catalog' );
        $placeholder_width = $size['height'];

        $output = '<div class="imagewrapper">';

        //$classes = array( 'imagewrapper' );
        $classes = array();
        $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

        if ( $image_link ) {

        $image       = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) );
        $image_class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $classes ) );
        $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_caption, $image ), $post->ID );

        } else {

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" />', wc_placeholder_img_src(), __( 'Placeholder', 'woocommerce' ) ), $post->ID );

        }
    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>
```

Just recently figured it out, so it possibly needs some finishing touches, but might point you in the right direction.

However, I'm not able to remove the product image from the gallery. The code that's supposed to make that happen is this (added to the product-thumbnails.php):

```
unset($attachment_ids);
```

All this does for me is removing ALL of the gallery thumbnails. Maybe you have figured this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
unset($attachment_ids); // Don't display first image in product gallery, only as product image
```

right before the foreach loop in product-thumbnails.php. It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hege got it right with the replacement code for page product-image.php

To remove just the first thumbnail, and not all of them, use

```
unset($attachment_ids[0]);
```

on product-thumbnails.php