# Want to remove woocommerce product featured image and put gallery 1st image instead

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-featured-image

Want to remove woocommerce product featured image and put gallery 1st image instead.
I can not find any plugin to do this and have tried all possible codes...
Have anyone did this before?

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to remove product featured image on detail product page or shop page?

There are php code to get featured image of product in the php template.

In woocommerce folder, single.php   or related php file as loop process.

Then you can change the code with gallery image code

Also about gallery.   I'd like to know what plugin you used , because functions to get gallery images are different per plugin

If you let me know details,  I can answer to you correctly

Comment: Hi thanks for response))
I want to replace it in detail product (single product) page. 
I found couple ready codes, but looks like they are outdated for latest versions of woocommerce.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636593/woocommerce-featured-image-different-than-product-image

I use WooCommerce Image Zoom plugin.

here is the link for example: https://sarkisiansjewelry.com/product/107-diamonds-shimmer-ring/